# Storyboard issue with a text field

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard, iboutlet

I'm having a Sign up View controller in storyboard and it keeps showing me the same error in console:

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key displayNameTextField.
```

I'm aware that this means that there's a connection that no longer exists and it causing it to crash. The problem is that I don't see any issues whatsoever. This is the View controller in Storyboard along with all the connections:

[image]

This is the code:

```
class SignUpVC: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var displayNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var registerButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTextFields()
    }

    func setupTextFields()
    {
        displayNameTextField.tintColor = UIColor.white
        displayNameTextField.textColor = UIColor.white
        displayNameTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 138/255, green: 82/255, blue: 108/255, alpha: 1.0)
        displayNameTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string    : displayNameTextField.placeholder!,
                                                                   attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.6)])
    handleTextFields()
}

 func handleTextFields()
    {
        displayNameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)

    }  

@objc func textFieldDidChange() {
        guard let username = usernameTextField.text,       !username.isEmpty,
              let displayName = displayNameTextField.text, !displayName.isEmpty,
              let email = emailTextField.text,             !email.isEmpty,
              let password = passwordTextField.text,       !password.isEmpty
        else
        {
            return
        }
        registerButton.isEnabled = true
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? It's one of those cases where this should be painfully obvious but I just don't see it.

Comment: Have you set the subclass of the view controller correctly? This warning normally means that hasn’t been set. The other possibility is that the item is of the wrong type.

Comment: @Fogmeister - Ugh, yes. That was the issue. Thank you. I knew it was something so obvious but I expected a connection or something that I just didn't see. Turned out the subclass of the view controller was not properly setup. This solved the issue. Thank you

Comment: No worries. Glad you got it working. :-)

Comment: Make that an answer and I will approve it to close this question.

Comment: @Fogmeister you should post your solution as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is usually an indication that you haven’t set the subclass of the view controller correctly.

Check in the attributes inspector in interface builder for that view controller.